# Trying to make a checkout page for an ecom website with dynamic button names

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a checkout page which will print a hard copy of the bill. But before printing the bill, i want to add a remove button which will allow the user to remove an item from the billing list individually.

I am trying to provide dynamic name to the remove button. I tried to use PUT and GET method both and the name is flashing on the address bar. But my sql query doesn't do anything. I tried to use echo just to check wether correct names are assigned to buttons, but echo doesn't produce any result.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$name`;";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>Cost</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $proName = $row['name'];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<div class='container-fluid col-sm-12'><td class='col-xs-2'>" . $row['name'] . "</td></div>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><form method='GET'><button id='printbtn'  name='$proName'>Remove</button></form></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            if (isset($_GET[$proName])) {
                echo $proName;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The result which i am trying to make is once i press the remove button, that particular item should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

$proName is declared inside the while loop and you are echo the $proName after the while loop so on that time $proName contains the last row name.

and it will only come inside the isset when you click on the last button.

Comment: i finally figured out, what the problem is. The above code is only working when the product contains only one word, for example - iphone, and when it contains more than one word for example - apple iphone, then echo is not working. So can you please explain why this is happening ?